# Jmeter- How to get response in Jmeter where API request in x-www-form-urlencoded format

Tags: jmeter

I have to automate the API in Jmeter. APi request is in x-www-from-urlencoded form.

Appreciate any response to resolve issue asap.

Thanks
leena

Answer (score 1):

It's enough to just send a [HTTP POST](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST) request

[image]

and JMeter will automatically add [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header with the value `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8` to it.

[image]

If you need to amend the `Content-Type` header you can always override it using [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager)